Pressure of mixture in rigid container after mixing
Hello Physics community!
I came upon this question:
"An insulated rigid tank is divided into two compartments by a partition. One compartment contains 3 kmol of O2, and the other compartment contains 5 kmol of CO2. Both gases are initially at 25 °C and 200 kPa. Now the partition is removed, and the two gases are allowed to mix. Assuming the surroundings are at 25 °C and both gases behave as ideal gases, determine the entropy change and exergy destruction associated with the process."
The first part of the answer is given as:
"Assumptions: Both gases and their mixture are ideal gases. The temperature and pressure in the tank will still be 25 °C and 200 kPa after the mixing. The entropy change of each component gas can be determined through:
$$ \Delta S_m = \sum N_i \cdot \Delta\overline{s_i} = \sum N_i \cdot (\overline{c_{pi}} \cdot \ln\left(\frac{T_{i,2}}{T_{i,1}}\right) - Ru\cdot \ln\left(y_{i,2} \cdot \frac{p_{m,2}}{p_{i,2}}\right) $$
As $P_{m,2} = P_{i,2} = 200\text{ kPa}$. It is obvious that the entropy change is independent of the composition of the mixture in this case and that it depends on only the mole fraction of the gases
of the mixture."
As you can see from the answer, they assumed that the mixture pressure at state 2 (so after the partition has been removed), the mixture pressure $p_{m,2}$ is exactly the same as the individual pressures $p_{02,1}$ and $p_{CO2,1}$ before the partition was removed.
From my understanding, it then implicates that the pressure hasn't changed at all.
Why is this the case? Or am I understanding this wrongly? Is this typical for ideal gases?
Thanks for the answer!

This question may be better suited for physics or chemistry community. Why would you assume the pressure should change?

This is not the Physics community...
